# How to forward content to log server with XMLHttpRequest()?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to log the content from `alert(allText);` to another server, for example, www.otherwebsite/logger?log=allText() without the `alert msg` that is current popping.

In other words, how can I generate another request to a log server with the information of `allText` using XMLHttpRequest?

I'm currently using this script to load the content but I'm not sure how to generate another request to my log server with `allText`

```
    <script>
    function readTextFile(file)
    {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                {
                    var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    alert(allText);
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }

    readTextFile("http://null.jsbin.com/runner");

</script>
```

For testing, I was running the script with jsbin.com

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a nested Post call to the api to which you want to post data:

```
<script>
    function readTextFile(file)
    {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                {
                    var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("POST", '/server', true);

                    //Send the proper header information along with the request
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                     //Call a function when the state changes.
                      if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
                       // Request finished. Do processing here.
                      }
                    }
                    xhr.send(allText); 
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }

    readTextFile("http://null.jsbin.com/runner");

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Using POST it much better.